# How to add query param in Cypress (JS)

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have to ask for help here. I'm still learning Cypress and trying to add query param to each URL and validate that some modal appears on the page when query param is added. So the way it looks:

urls = [
"/en/link1/",
"/en/link2/",
"/en/link3/",
]

queryParam = [
"?param1",
"?param2",
"?param3",
]

I need to write code that would do for me

- /en/link1/?param1
- /en/link2/?param1
- /en/link3/?param1
- checkCondition()
- 
- /en/link1/?param2
- /en/link2/?param2
- /en/link3/?param2
- checkCondition()

and so on...

Could you please advise me how to do this? I'd rly appreciate any advice/link to material. Thanks a lot and happy coding!

### SOLUTION (kudos to @Alapan Das)

```
describe("My test", () => {
  urls.forEach(url => {
    params.forEach(param => {
      it(`should check smthng`, () => {
        cy.visit(url + param)
        cy.checkCondition()
      })
    })
  })
```

Comment: Instead of editing your question with the solution, you should mark Alapan's answer as the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested ForEach Loops to iterate over both arrays and make the combinations like this:

```js
const urls = ['/en/link1/', '/en/link2/', '/en/link3/']

const params = ['?param1', '?param2', '?param3']

urls.forEach((url) => {
  params.forEach((param) => {
    console.log(url + param)
  })
  checkCondition()
})
```

Upon execution:

[image: Console Execution of js snippet]

Comment: thanks a lot !!! did that and it worked!  added the final code into description (for future readers in need :))

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cy.request` version taking options as argument: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request#Options

```
cy.request({
  url: "/en/link1",
  qs: {
    "param2": "test"
 }
})
```